# Javascript recursive number permutations

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

When I feed this function 85, it only returns 85. I don't understand why is not recursively calling itself again with 5 as the first number.

```
console.log(PermutationStep(85));

function PermutationStep(num) { 
  var perms = [];

  rec(String(num), String(num).length, [], '');
  return perms;

  function rec(num, numLength, used, currPerm) {
    console.log(currPerm);
    if (currPerm.length === numLength) {
      perms.push(num);
    }
    for (var j=0; j<numLength; j++) {
      if (used[j]) continue;
      else {
        used[j]=true;
        rec(num, numLength, used, currPerm+num[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to set `used[j]` back to `false` after rec in for-loop is complete.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should push `currPerm` instead of `num` when length is reached.
2. Make `used[j]` available again after it was tracked.
3. It may produce duplicate result, like `885`, you need to make sure its not tracking the same value.

```js
console.log(PermutationStep(85));
console.log(PermutationStep(885));

function PermutationStep(num) { 
  var perms = [];
  
  // Convert number to char array.
  var str = ('' + num).split('');
  var length = str.length;
  // sort by alphabetical order.
  str.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  // Create used map.
  var used = str.map(function() {
    return false;
  });

  rec(str, '');
  return perms;

  // Not that javascript can reference value from outer function scope,
  // So we don't need to pass length and used each time, like you treat with perms.
  function rec(num, currPerm) {
    console.log(currPerm);
    if (currPerm.length === length) {
      // Put the constructed string here, not num
      perms.push(currPerm);
    }
    var prev = null, ch;
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (used[j]) {
        continue;
      }
      ch = str[j];
      if (prev === ch) { 
        // If current char is same wih previous, there's more than 2 ch in the string,
        // So we need to skip to prevent duplicate result.
        continue;
      }
      used[j] = true;
      rec(num, currPerm + ch);
      // Make the number usable again.
      used[j]=false;
      prev = ch;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if used is initially [], then after the first recursive call it would be [true] and j =1. used[1] is false so why wouldnt it make a second recursive call?

Comment: Because you go into check the 2nd number, which is the 2nd nested `rec`, it'll mark `used[1]` to `true`. So when you go back to 1st `rec`, and loop to `j = 1`, the used is `[true, true]`, so it is skipped.

Comment: When you pass `rec(num, numLength, used, currPerm+num[j]);`, note that javascript pass the reference pointer to `used` to `rec`, so if you modify `used` in the nested function, it'll also modify the outer function that use it.

Comment: Even if you use `used.slice(0)` to pass a copy of used to nested `rec`, you still have to set it back to false after nest `rec` complete, for example, after `index 0`'s result is done(`85`), the `used` is `[true, undefined]` then at `j = 1`, if you didn't set `used[0]` back to false, you'll pass `[true, true]` to nest, which will generate nothing because it sees that all used is true.

Comment: I just tried it with used.slice(0) and it works without setting back false

Comment: You mean simply change `rec(num, numLength, used, currPerm+num[j]);` to `rec(num, numLength, used.slice(0), currPerm+num[j]);` ?

Comment: Hmm, doing what you said just won't give me the correct result. I only get `[85]` if I change that line.

Comment: I get `584` from what you paste, is that what you expect?